# Is PrincipalContext thread-safe in C#?

Tags: .net

I'm recreating the same PrincipalContext over and over again. Is it safe to shove it in a static field and just reuse one instance across threads?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be yes... assuming you don't dispose it. The initialization routine uses internal locks to prevent double-initialization. And once initialized, it is immutable (again, other than to be disposed).

Answer (score -1):

Quoting MSDN:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Of course, this is the standard answer for any type that isn't explicitly designed to be thread-safe. It might be that `PrincipalContext` is thread-safe, but you shouldn't rely on it - it would be just an implementation detail, not a contractual guarantee.

As for whether it makes more sense to synchronize access to a single instance or create a new one for each thread/operation, you'll need to profile your application. Does it make a significant difference? Is your application in any way constrained by the cost of the `PrincipalContext`? Only you can answer that :)